# Laravel is not grabbing all my input values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am a newbie to laravel and I've been trying to grab form input values and submit to the database but i've been having errors. 
Please i would be happy if you can help me look through it and help check where i am missing the input values.

> [2018-11-23 11:20:26] development.ERROR: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1048 Column 'local_govt_id' cannot be null (SQL:
>   insert into `users_signedups` (`state_id`, `local_govt_id`,
>   `first_name`, `surname`, `phone_number`, `date_of_birth`, `title`,
>   `education_level_id`, `discipline`, `work_address`, `res_address`,
>   `occupation`, `gender`, `marital_status`, `make_donations`,
>   `be_a_member`, `be_a_volunteer`, `about_you`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , lawalmariamyetunde@gmail.com, , 2018-11-23 11:20:23, 2018-11-23
>   11:20:23)) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'local_govt_id' cannot be
>   null (SQL: insert into `users_signedups` (`state_id`, `local_govt_id`,
>   `first_name`, `surname`, `phone_number`, `date_of_birth`, `title`,
>   `education_level_id`, `discipline`, `work_address`, `res_address`,
>   `occupation`, `gender`, `marital_status`, `make_donations`,
>   `be_a_member`, `be_a_volunteer`, `about_you`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
>   , app@gmail.com, , 2018-11-23 11:20:23, 2018-11-23 11:20:23)) at
>   C:\Users\USER\

my controller is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\users_signedup;



class UsersSignedupController extends Controller
{


    public function signup(Request $request)
    {

        return view('signup');
    }


    public function postUserSignupDetails(Request $request)
    {

        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'state_id' => 'required',
            'local_govt_id' => 'required',
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required',
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'education_level_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'discipline' => 'required',
            'res_address' => 'required',
            'work_address' => 'required',
            'occupation' => 'required',
            'gender' => 'required|numeric',
            'marital_status' => 'required|numeric',
            'make_donations' => 'numeric',
            'be_a_member' => 'numeric',
            'be_a_volunteer' => 'numeric',
            'about_you' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|unique:users_signedups',
            'password' => 'required'

        ]);




    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // $users_signedup = $request->session()->get('users_signedup');
        $userModel = new users_signedup;

        //$userModel = new UserModel;
//        dd($request->email);
//        $request->state_id
        $userModel->state_id = $request->state_id;
        $userModel->local_govt_id = $request->local_govt_id;
        $userModel->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $userModel->surname = $request->surname;
        $userModel->phone_number = $request->phone_number;
        $userModel->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
        $userModel->title = $request->title;
        $userModel->education_level_id = $request->education_level_id;
        $userModel->discipline = $request->discipline;
        $userModel->work_address = $request->work_address;
        $userModel->res_address = $request->res_address;
        $userModel->occupation = $request->occupation;
        $userModel->gender = $request->gender;
        $userModel->marital_status = $request->marital_status;
        $userModel->make_donations = $request->make_donations;
        $userModel->be_a_member = $request->be_a_member;
        $userModel->be_a_volunteer = $request->be_a_volunteer;
        $userModel->about_you = $request->about_you;
        $userModel->email = $request->email;
        $userModel->password = $request->password;
       $userModel->save();


        return redirect('/signup/success');
    }
```

my model is

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class users_signedup extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}
```

my view is

```
<form action="signup/store" method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <select class="form-control"  name="state_id" placeholder="Choose your State of Residence" required>
                                        <option value="">Choose your State of Residence</option>
                                        <option value="1">Abia State</option>


                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <select class="form-control"  name="local_govt_id" placeholder="Choose your Local Government Area" required>
                                        <option value="">Choose your Local Government Area</option>
                                        <option value="1">Umahia</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname" placeholder="Surname" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date_of_birth" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <select class="form-control"  name="title" placeholder="Title" required>
                                        <option value="">Choose your Title</option>
                                        <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
                                        <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
                                        <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
                                        <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
                                        <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
                                        <option value="Chief">Chief</option>
                                        <option value="Dr.">Dr.</option>
                                        <option value="Hon.">Hon.</option>



                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="marital_status" placeholder="Marital Status" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                    <select class="form-control"  name="education_level_id" placeholder="Education Level" required>
                                        <option value="">Choose your Education Level</option>
                                        <option value="none">No Education</option>
                                        <option value="primary">Primary</option>
                                        <option value="secondary">Secondary</option>
                                        <option value="tertiary">Tertiary</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="discipline" placeholder="Discipline" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="res_address" data-gramm="true" spellcheck="false" data-gramm_editor="true" placeholder="Residential Address" required="required"></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="work_address" data-gramm="true" spellcheck="false" data-gramm_editor="true" placeholder="Workplace Address" required="required">
                                        {{ route('signup') }}
                                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    </textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="occupation" placeholder="Occupation" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    {{--<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfXfnwUAAAAAIJW_OYS6viKZ-ydqSn5_-obFdys"></div>--}}
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>
                                <button class="sub-btn donate-btn more-btn hvr-shutter-out-horizontal">send</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Comment: Error is about something else. Your provided data doesn't comply tables constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently just calling the name of the fields from the request object. The correct code would be

```
$model->input = $request->input('input_name');
```

Take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$inputData = $request->all()

users_signedup::create($inputData);
```

OR

```
DB::table('users_signedup')->insert($inputData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="***enter default value***">Choose your Local Government Area</option>
```

You need to force users to select an option or you can assign a default value.
 Also you can make this field in your database **nullable** or with a default value. 
Please check all of your inputs about null options. Your whole code seems fine to me except this.